# I am unable to access 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, flask, port, replit

I am developing an app in repl.it, when I run the code this is output:

```
  * Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

this is my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import subprocess
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

but I am unable to open 127.0.0.1:5000 and I'm not sure why or how to fix it; would really appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the server that repl.it runs on? You're trying to access localhost

Comment: do you mean the server which my code runs on?

Comment: Yes, you're running the code in repl.it so their server isn't the same one you're using to try and access localhost on via your web browser

Comment: I’m not sure, I presumed the code ran on 127.0.0.1:5000. Sorry I’m not great at all this yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For running flask in repl.it, make sure you're using their flask template.
Afterwards, change your app.run to:

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

And while running, a window should appear with the site above the terminal.
You should also be able to access it via
https://[project name].[replit username].repl.co

You can see an example here at the bottom:
https://replit.com/talk/learn/Flask-Tutorial-Part-1-the-basics/26272